Writing LaTeX tables with Lua
I am trying to automatically create tables in LaTeX through a Lua script I wrote. On the Lua side everything works fine, I even get usable LaTeX code that I can copy and paste. My LaTeX document looks something like this:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\true}{1}
\newcommand{\false}{0}

\directlua{require 'truth.lua'}
\newcommand{\truth}[1]{\directlua{tex.print(CreateLatexTable(#1))}}

\begin{document}
    \truth{'p','!p'}
\end{document}

The function CreateLatexTable produces the following code, which is then passed to tex.print:
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$p$ & $¬p$ \\ 
\hline
$\false $ & $\true $ \\ 
$\true $ & $\false $ \\ 
\end{tabular}

However I get no \hline and the first value under $p$ says "height 0". Also the ¬ disappeared. Other symbols seem to work fine.

The following four errors get raised:
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.10    \truth{'p','!p'}

! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\hline ->\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule 
                                         \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.10    \truth{'p','!p'}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\futurelet 
l.10    \truth{'p','!p'}

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\futurelet 
l.10    \truth{'p','!p'}


if you provide the code we can debug it, without it's rather hard to say anything.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you willing to disclose the contents of truth.lua?

@DavidCarlisle The code is rather long (~450 lines and probably not well written). I clarified in my answer what the code produces and passes on to tex.print. I can of course upload the code if it is required.

You can always provide a smaller example (but I guessed one this time, see my answer)

@DavidCarlisle I see. I assumed the problem happens between Lua and LaTeX so it isn't necessary, though it would have clarified everything a bit I guess.

@AnniLua examples carify and more important make it easier for people to test their answers

You haven't really shown an example but I assume something like this
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\true}{1}
\newcommand{\false}{0}

\directlua{require 'truth.lua'}
\newcommand{\truth}[1]{\directlua{tex.print(CreateLatexTable(#1))}}

\begin{document}
    \truth{'p','!p'}
\end{document}


function CreateLatexTable (a,b)
return [[
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$]] .. a .. '$ & $' .. b .. [[$ \\ 
\hline
$\false $ & $\true $ \\ 
$\true $ & $\false $ \\ 
\end{tabular}
]]
end
-- debuging print (CreateLatexTable('p','!p'))

which produces
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...

l.10     \truth{'p','!p'}
                       
?

If you put the \hline straight after the \\ it is easier to see the problem.
function CreateLatexTable (a,b)
return [[
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$]] .. a .. '$ & $' .. b .. [[$ \\\hline
$\false $ & $\true $ \\ 
$\true $ & $\false $ \\ 
\end{tabular}
]]
end
-- print (CreateLatexTable('p','!p'))

produces no error but the warnings:
Missing character: There is no 
 (U+000A) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 
 (U+000A) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 
 (U+000A) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 
 (U+000A) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

the problem is that the line end is character 10 which is just a (missing) character in latex, so interferes. You can locally make it act like a space character by giving it catcode 10
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\true}{1}
\newcommand{\false}{0}

\directlua{require 'truth.lua'}
\newcommand{\truth}[1]{{\catcode10=10 \directlua{tex.print(CreateLatexTable(#1))}}}

\begin{document}
    \truth{'p','!p'}
\end{document}

produces


This pretty much solved it. Thank you so much. Now what's missing is the ¬ character, though for that one I can just use \neg. I guess it would still work without the newlines and be easier to implement.

@AnniLua if you use unicode-math package you can use unicode characters directly in math

Yeah, that solves it too, thanks!

The fontspec package works too. I removed it when creating my minimal example.

@AnniLua by default fontspec doesn't change the math fonts oh apart from the roman font so I guess that would work here
